# DOM elements not displayed correctly, during protractor test

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor, automated-tests, e2e-testing

I test an Angular application with protractor and since today the DOM-elements are not displayed correctly during the testing. I am using it on macOS.

What I tried to solve the problem is:

- uninstall protractor and reinstall
- uninstall webdriver-manager and reinstall
- remove all node_modules and did `yarn install` again
- Tried to find another person who has the same problem here

  Used Versions:

  `"protractor": "5.2.2",
  "protractor-cucumber-framework": "^1.0.1",
  "webdriver-manager": "12.0.6"`

And here is a screenshot of how it looks like:

#### screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Another thing is, the tests are green and in the DOM everything is okay, but debugging is a bit difficult, when you don't see anything.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Also, what does your conf file look like.

Comment: No there is no error message. Everything is like before. Only thing that changed is that I don't see anymore whats going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My acquaintance encountered it a while time ago. 
I know that he resolved it by decreasing Chrome browser version from 66 to 65 and then updated back. Try to play around with your browser, there is no a problem with the protractor

Comment: I will give it a try. This would be the second time, that I have problems with the chrome version.

Comment: This was the solution. Chrome updated itself to `v:67` and after installing `v:66` it works. But I did not upgrade again and disabled automatic update.

Comment: year, exactly as I thought. Good decision for disabling auto update. Goodluck!

Comment: Thank you! This helped me and hopefully other a lot!